# JavaFX: Embedding encoded image in .FXML file

Tags: image, base64, javafx, fxml

I would like to embed an encoded image into an FXML (i need this in that I'm coding a converter between svg and fxml). 
I tried with this:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="153.0" layoutY="94.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYEAYAAACw5+G7AAAABmJLR0T///////8JWPfcAAAA CXBIWXMAAABIAAAASABGyWs+AAAACXZwQWcAAAAYAAAAGAB4TKWmAAAI1UlEQVRYw61YS4gc VRf+7r1Vt+pWdfdMd0/P9PTMOCGJBpNI4gPiRrPQnSKIigQEN4LgQoTgwpU7QYOggop7UVA3 ESMEDKiJmIlEhUwS85pM5tGP6Wemn/V2cVJ2xxjCr//d3K66davOd873nXNus+jGwH8cjuM4 jgN0Op1OpwOEYRiGIcAY54wBQgihaUAqlUwmkwDnnEcRwBhjmvbvv8v+VwCO43muC1y6dOHC 0hJQKhWL5TIghKYJARQK09PpNDA1lc9nMoBlWVYyCdRqtdrmJrC+vr5eqQAAYwAwOzs3VygA 09NTU1NTBIhW/k8AoigMgwBYWbl2rVgEfvnl998XF4F6vVq9dg2YmUkmGQNyOSn7fYBzxlx3 uF8IIYQANE3XlaI7ySRQrfq+YQBra9Vqrwdks7nczAzw6KOPPPLww0AymUwmEncGdFsAnud5 vg9cvbq8fPUq0GiUSpUK0GqVSouLgBC9XqkEWBbn3S6g62HougDnUaTrIx9gjHE+vA4C8r3r apquA5ubvp9IAL0eY9kskMnMzc3PA/feu3v3nj0UmXz+9gD+Yl8URVEQEHejCKhUyuVKBbBt KcMQaDY3N5eWgPHxKNrYIGo4Du2UEghDQCkgioRgDBg1enTE9w2DZtsG+n2g23Wc1VVASt9P JoFOp93u9YBqVdMaDWBiIpNJp2+NyC3yKZfJ8EwmnVYKuHLl119//BHQ9SCoVgEpLcs0ASkB 0xz1LGNCAFE09LIQAOdCcA6EITkoikjcntfrtVo0dzr0PgBw3VrtwgXAMAqFmRmA87Ex2wba 7Xa70wFSqVQqmfwHAO02IfZ9ikCjsbp6/jwA9HrlMpBIJBKmCWhaFHFOESNvxlnmDmJjBKDV qtfX1gDfJ8OF4FzXAc41jTHAMDgfDIBy+cKFEyeA3bvn5rZvB8rlanVjA0gkSBucUyT+AlAs rq8Xi0A6nUgwBpRKKyvnzgGZjG1ns2TCKLfjEYacB8HNstd1Sp+jhl+/XqksLwOu2+/3+yRu 0wTCUNelJACjtJOSMd8HVlfPnv3pJ0CpfH7vXqBebzSaTSCXy2YzGUCL02K93my2WgBjjUal AqTTqVQqBei6rqdSQBRx7vv/5NmbRfp3rnc6jcb6OjAYtNutFqAUGRqGJOIo4lxKQErSjqZR vYjXB4NajbSRyVAkKpUwHAGwsVGt1moAY0KEIeC6m5uNBpDLFQrT08Tt2POGAXz00a5djz0G vPLK2bPHjo36nQrSxx/v3Ll/P/DSSwsLX30FNJvV6vo68O23L7546BDw9NOff/7GG8DXXx84 8NZbuON4/vkjR95/H+h2iXqtFucTE0AQBEEQAFq/3+12uwBjvh+GgKZJSRRQKp0G4ir5wQfb tu3bB7z22tLSwgLw3ntbt+7bB7z66pUrCwuxEoajUllZuXiR9ofhaMQMI5EAnnnm8OG33yYq cQ588cWTT77+OnDgwNGjH344rNxxpR4Mer1GA/A8XbdtYDAYDBwH0FzXdXs9yt+eB1iWlEoR EEqLN5d6IegF8TBNw5CSPFQqjT4XRf0+oGk3c1sITaP3kYGc0/xXVtE0zTQBxug5IhYQBI7j +6Q53wc870YEhkWM8zAEut1Op9EA0unBoNEAdF2psbGbuT1aadfW/vjj1Cmg3a7Xy+VRQ4TQ 9SGnRx1gWeRhKYdiH64bBj3PuWHQfs4BxrrdXo9ieJPWDMMwLGt4o9msVFZWgMXF48e/+QZ4 553Z2fvvH64fOjQ398ADw+vPPnv88ZdfJs+N1nPGdJ2Kla6P1ovYcM6lpAjcvM65ZeVygBDj 44UCucI0KVK0j3NNA3T9RouilG3bNlCrNRpKAUqZplJAGHpevT588VNPffrpwYNAFGmaYVDa Mwzg8OFnn33zTfKUlMBzzx058u67wJdfPvHEwYPD/S+88N13n3wypEYQUG8kpWUlEsPnUqlC Yds2IJXK5ebngXL5zJnvvweEsKxUCjAMxmwbME3TNAyAua7rel4ULSycPn36NJDLed7KCtBu Ly+fPDnsMjknT0QReUCIeI65SpRhjICRCqjAUaEiT3NOkeGccyEApXK5LVuAZHJmZscOIAg8 z/OG1Lt06dSpo0cBy5qc3L4d6HTC0DCA++7btWvnToDruq5rGpDJjI+PjQHj41u27NkDhKFS 2ezQ8JjTUlJ+FsIwTBMQQkoSHYk5zh6apmlKAbpO67HhsWFC0LVtp1L5PNDr9XrtNqCUZY2N Af1+rXb5MsC5UrZN30kkgOnpfH5ycoRy8Y/ZWeo9XJdzpYBCYdeu/fupDihFBpD4yJNxtogB MsZYbGicRWiWcnRfvC5lJjMzAwBKSQkopZRhAI6zuVkqAcXi0tL588D8/D337N0L+D4lkGw2 k6HO4G8Ahk0SNWUTE3fdtXs3oFQ2Oz8PBEEUUV4misSejimkaYYRAzUMQEqaY0/HAHSdOC8E JY8goN5L0+hEd+3amTM//wyY5sTE3XcD/b7nCUEHpOnpW7vRW5qAQoFORrVao9HpANnsli17 9wKDAR1EHIfOCYah61T6yTAhYmDDCBClqNfRNF3XdaKUUiRC6oWo8p87d/LksWNAq9XvRxHg OIZBVKFWw7ZtezRb3hZAfIKani4U8nng+vUgME3A88bHd+wAVlZ6PaWAy5fL5XYbcJzBgAoW Y2FInyONxE0aaccwbDuVogIURcDS0rlzv/0G/PDDiRPHjwOLi+Wy4wCDgaZNTgJjY4mEZQHZ bDabTuO247bH6RjI9u1bt87PEzWkBNbWqOlbXS2VlpeBzc0w9DxgYqLbbTYByzLNdhswDCnj dCsl4PvVar0OuK7nUb0ZDACgWh0MDIN6r/l5YM+ehx568MEhgDuNf32ov3jx0qWrV4FisVQa bSFmZ6em0mlgbq5QKBTI84kEUC4Xi6USsLFRrzebQ63Nzs7MFApAPj85mc1SZb7T2eI/Afj7 iHf7vu8HAdDtUr/vODeaLY1zzgHTVMo0qXeiyFCd+K9/q/wJwRXXOxs1rPEAAAAASUVORK5C YII= " preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

As you can see I used the standard way I would do with HTML or CSS, passing a data url with the Base64 encoding of the image. 
In this case it does not return any error, but the image is not displayed (passing a url to the same image as a file works, but this is not what I want).

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

I was able to do this but not in FXML

```
String rocketImgStr = "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";
BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
ByteArrayInputStream rocketInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(rocketImgStr));

Image rocketImg = new Image(rocketInputStream);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the String for the `url` attribute of the `Image` in the question, you can see that it has spaces in it, so it is not well-formed.

However, in another [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000160/1155209), there is an Image URL string encoding that has no spaces in it and is well formed.

If the corrupted Image URL string from the question is replaced with the correctly encoded value, then the image will be displayed (otherwise the image display will silently fail).

This is quite an old question (ten years), so it is possible that originally this feature was not supported and the image URL decoding support was added to JavaFX in a relatively recent release.  For instance, support for data URL encoding of CSS stylesheets was only added in the JavaFX 17 release.  And earlier Image javadoc than JavaFX 17 does not mention the feature.

From the [Image](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) javadoc:

> The RFC 2397 "data" scheme for URLs is supported in addition to the
> protocol handlers that are registered for the application. If a URL
> uses the "data" scheme, the data must be base64-encoded and the MIME
> type must either be empty or a subtype of the image type.

**Example App**

[image: example]

*ImageScene.fxml*

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="153.0" layoutY="94.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="data:image/png;base64,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" preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

*ImageDataApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageDataApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                ImageDataApp.class.getResource(
                        "ImageScene.fxml"
                )
        );
        
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        loader.load()
                )
        );
        
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Side note for IntelliJ users*

My IDE (Idea 2022.1.2), in the editor, highlights the URL image string in red and indicates that it is a malformed file path, but that is misleading and a shortcoming of the IDE.  The IDE does not understand the correctly encoded image data URLs in FXML.  The program will execute fine despite the IDE highlighting error.