# JavaFX corrupted Image from Server makes app crash

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I'm trying to convert Base64 Image Strings and some URLs to image form but one or more of the images I get from the server seem to be corrupted. I can pick them out per hand but I need a code solution for this. I wrote the method prepareAvatar which gets a String avatar that is either a Base64 String or an URL, like imgur or something like that.

```
    public Circle prepareAvatar(String avatar) {
        Image image;
        if (avatar == null || avatar.equals("")) {
            image = defaultAvatar;
        }else{
            Image newImage = new Image(avatar);
            if(newImage == null){
                image = defaultAvatar;
            }else{
                image = newImage;
            }

        }
        Circle avatarCircle = new Circle();
        avatarCircle.setRadius(Constants.AVATAR_SIZE);
        avatarCircle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        avatarCircle.setFill(new ImagePattern(image));
        return avatarCircle;
    }
```

At the moment I just try to filter out alle avatars which are null or "" and that seems to work. Because I get the exception "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image must be non-null" I tried to create a new Instance of Image newImage and just check whether it is not null. That doesn't seem to work and I still get the same exception.
Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image must be non-null
    at com.sun.prism.paint.ImagePattern.<init>(ImagePattern.java:47)
    at com.sun.prism.paint.ImagePattern.<init>(ImagePattern.java:65)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createImagePatternPaint(QuantumToolkit.java:981)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getPaint(Toolkit.java:680)
    at javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern.acc_getPlatformPaint(ImagePattern.java:292)
    at javafx.scene.paint.Paint$1.getPlatformPaint(Paint.java:48)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.updatePGShape(Shape.java:963)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Shape.doUpdatePeer(Shape.java:998)
    at javafx.scene.shape.Shape$1.doUpdatePeer(Shape.java:131)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.ShapeHelper.updatePeerImpl(ShapeHelper.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.CircleHelper.updatePeerImpl(CircleHelper.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.updatePeer(NodeHelper.java:103)
    at javafx.scene.Node.syncPeer(Node.java:715)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2399)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "<local2>" is null
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2545)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:420)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:555)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:353)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: "_gets a String avatar that is either a Base64 String or a URL_" – Then you need to handle both cases. The `Image(String)` constructor expects a URL or a resource name. So, if `avatar` is a URL, then you can just pass it to the constructor. But if `avatar` is a Base64-encoded string, then you need to decode the string into bytes, wrap the bytes in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, and then pass the stream to the `Image(InputStream)` constructor.

Comment: Also, `newImage == null` can _never_ be true in your code. A constructor either returns a new instance of the class, or throws an exception; it cannot return `null`. The only other thing I can imagine being `null` in the code you've shown is `defaultAvatar`. Make sure that field is not `null`.

Comment: @Slaw 1. Not true, the image constructor accepts either. 2. The Image is indeed not null, the exception happens deep in the JavaFX internals. Looking at the source of the topmost stack entries and the Image with a debugger, it is actually the PlatformImage that is null.

Comment: @Clashsoft **(1)** Please clarify. As far as I know, there's nothing false in my first comment. I'm not talking about a `data` **URL**, but a plain Base64-encoded string. Though I suppose you could do `"data:base64," + avatar` instead of the `InputStream` wrapper I previously suggested. But I'm pretty sure the acceptance of `data` URLs is a very recent thing, and this question is tagged [tag:javafx-8]. **(2)** You're right, but I was mostly commenting on the fact that `if (newImage == null)` is entirely pointless, because that condition can never evaluate to true at that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Java exception handling. You have to catch the exceptions which may result from a failed image generation. If you are using an IDE you can let that create this for you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

I also doubt that Base64 encoded images can be decoded this way at all. You will probably have to convert them back to a real image by other means. [Convert base64 string to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979842/convert-base64-string-to-image) or convert the raw encoded data to a data URL as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482868/4262407

Comment: This exception cannot be caught. Looking at the stacktrace, it is not triggered directly by user code, but in a background thread.